# Scala Native - How to convert Int to Ptr[CInt]?

Tags: scala, scala-native

What's the right way to convert VM's `Int` to unmanaged `CInt` pointer from `scala.scalanative.unsafe`?

```scala
val num: Int = 5
val nativeInt: Ptr[CInt] = // ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working for me:

```scala
def toCIntPtr(num: Int)(using z: Zone): Ptr[CInt] = {
    val nativeInt: Ptr[CInt] = alloc[CInt](sizeof[CInt])
    !nativeInt = num
    nativeInt
}

// implicit zone present
val num: Int = 5
val nativeInt: Ptr[CInt] = toCIntPtr(num)
```